# spiral forward orbits of analytic functions near repelling fixed points

Tags: fixed-point-theorems, analytic-functions

An anonymous referee informs me that forward orbits near fixed points of analytic functions, such that the members of the forward orbits lie on spirals, are well-known. His citation for this (p. 31 of "Complex Dynamics", Carleson and Gamelin, Springer 1993) does not mention such spirals explicitly. Is there a discussion of these spirals in the literature, especially of equations they satisfy?